# Checking for a month between two dates in excel

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

I'm writing a SUMIFS statement and I want one of criteria to check for a specific month.

I have a table where a user can input a starting date in one cell, and an ending date in a different cell.

How do I get excel to check if there's a specific month within these two dates?

Comment: Please read the help here about how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an Array formula like this (please Keep in mind to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to insert the formula):

[image]

```
=SUM(IF((MONTH($A$6:$A$9)<=$2)*(MONTH($B$6:$B$9)>=D$2),$C$6:$C$9,0))
```

The formula should read like this if it's entered correctly:

```
{=SUM(IF((MONTH($A$6:$A$9)<=$2)*(MONTH($B$6:$B$9)>=D$2),$C$6:$C$9,0))}
```